# I can't use useMutation or useQuery Apollo Client 3.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo

```
  import { useMutation } from '@apollo/client';;
        
  function LockedBlog() {
  const [lockedBlog] = useMutation(LOCKED_BLOG);
  };

  class EditBlog extends Component {
    state = {
      ...initialState
    };
```

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./light.scss";
import App from "./components/App";
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/client'
import { ApolloClient } from '@apollo/client/core';
import {ApolloLink} from 'apollo-link';
import {SubscriptionClient} from 'subscriptions-transport-ws';
import {WebSocketLink} from 'apollo-link-ws';
import {createHttpLink} from 'apollo-link-http';
import {InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client/cache';
import { onError } from 'apollo-link-error';

const errorLink = onError(({ networkError, graphQLErrors }) => {
  if (graphQLErrors) {
    graphQLErrors.map(({ message, locations, path }) =>
      console.log(
        `[GraphQL error]: Message: ${message}, Location: ${locations}, Path: ${path}`,
      ),
    );
  }
  if (networkError) console.log(`[Network error]: ${networkError}`);
});

const middlewareLink = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  operation.setContext({
    headers: {
      authorization: localStorage.getItem('token') || null
    }
  });
  return forward(operation);
});

const wsLink = new WebSocketLink(
  new SubscriptionClient("ws://localhost:4004/graphql", {
    reconnect: true,
  }),
);

const httpLink = middlewareLink.concat(
  createHttpLink({
    uri: "http://localhost:4004/graphql",
  })
);

const hasSubscriptionOperation = ({query: {definitions}}) => {
  return definitions.some(({kind, operation}) => kind === 'OperationDefinition' && operation === 'subscription');
}

const link = ApolloLink.split(
  hasSubscriptionOperation,
  wsLink,
  httpLink,
  errorLink,
);

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.Fragment>
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <App />
    </ApolloProvider>
  </React.Fragment>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

my package.json

```
"@apollo/client": "^3.0.2",
"@apollo/react-hooks": "^3.1.5",
"@material-ui/core": "^4.10.2",
"@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
"@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
"Dante2": "^0.5.0-rc4",
"apollo-boost": "^0.4.9",
"apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.6.6",
"apollo-client": "^2.6.10",
"apollo-link": "^1.2.14",
"apollo-link-error": "^1.1.13",
"apollo-link-http": "^1.5.17",
"apollo-link-ws": "^1.0.20",
"apollo-upload-client": "^13.0.0",
"env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
"graphql": "^15.1.0",
"graphql-tag": "^2.10.4",
"jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
"lodash.flowright": "^3.5.0",
"moment": "^2.27.0",
"node-sass": "^4.14.1",
"prismjs": "^1.20.0",
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-dom": "^16.13.1",
"react-dropzone": "^11.0.1",
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
"react-scripts": "3.4.1",
"subscriptions-transport-ws": "^0.9.16"
```

i get this error when i use it. i migrated apollo client 3.0

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

there are many people who get the same error here. and no solution was found.
https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/3454

**SOLVED**

```
import { withApollo } from '@apollo/client/react/hoc';

// class component 

componentDidMount() {
    this.lockedBlog(true);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.lockedBlog(false);
  }

  lockedBlog = locked => {
    const { id } = this.props.match.params;
    this.props.client
      .mutate({
        variables: { id, locked },
        mutation: gql`
          mutation($id: ID!, $locked: Boolean!) {
            lockedBlog(id: $id, data: { locked: $locked }) {
              locked
            }
          }
        `
      })
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

and export

```
export default withApollo(EditBlog);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks

Hooks **can't be used within event handlers** - you can use them only within 'rendering flow' (main FC body) ... and there is requirement for constant order of calling hooks ... so **not in conditional blocks** (functions/handlers/etc.).

### update:

```
const LockedBlog = (props) => {
  const [lockedBlog] = useMutation(LOCKED_BLOG);
  
  lockedBlogHandler = (e, someId) => {
    // const { id } = props.match.params;
    lockedBlog({variables:{ Your data that you have passed }}) // call invoker returned from useMutation
    // with variables prepared from component props, handler passed someId, etc.
    console.log(someId);
  };
  return (
    <Button onClick={lockedBlogHandler} >
    // search docs how to pass args into handler
```

Comment: this is not important right now i did this for testing purposes, i get the same error anywhere. * You did not need to give  - points. @xadm

Comment: **bad usage** doesn't need a solution, adjust code to environment requirements described in docs .... entire component/app code to show usage context?

Comment: thanks , i have question. this function is already working in class. like this. '''   componentDidMount() {
    this.lockedBlog(true);
  } ' and  i want to run this function when the page load, how will i do it other than component?  it works with componentDidmount. how can i do without it? @xadm

Comment: I wrote clearly in the question. the function is already in class. i updated code

Comment: **hooks are only for functional components** - use `<Mutation/>` component in class

Comment: well i tried functional comp but same error, out class component  function LockedBlog(locked) {
  const lockedBlog = useMutation(LOCKED_BLOG);
  console.log(locked); i updted code can you see that please ? 
};

Comment: The function gives an error even though it is not running @xadm

Comment: so if I write useMutation anywhere, the system gives an error.

Comment: You can't use it anywhere, only in FC body, see update

Comment: ahh i got it !! thanks. and i solved my problem i solved with withApollo can you check my code update  ? thats ok ? this code running with componentdidmount. @xadm

Comment: You should explain usage/context/requirements at the beggining ... you can do the same using `useMutation` with `useEffect` - replacement for cDM/cWU

Comment: sorry about this. well how can i use this code with useEffect ? without componentdidmount ? can you update your code for me ? @xadm

Comment: this will be very useful to me. I would appreciate if you update.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to declare inside any function. You have to declare your main function component in between. Like this

```
const [lockedBlog] = useMutation(LOCKED_BLOG);

lockedBlog = locked => {
 const { id } = this.props.match.params;
 lockedBlog({variables:{ Your data that you have passed }})
 console.log(locked);
};
```

If more details forhow to use useMutation then here is [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/)

Comment: const [lockedBlog] = useMutation(LOCKED_BLOG);  I also get an error when I use this alone. I don't need to run it.

Comment: I get a react error when I use useMutation anywhere. https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/3454 same error

Comment: Is this lackedBlog is in the functional component or class component ?